# DHCP not "working" for either Wifi or Ethernet. Works fine on static. 18.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

just as the title states.   (I pretty much just use wifi so for this question I'll just use wifi as an example).

I don't know what I did, but it was many moons ago.   I messed up something on my xubuntu 18.04 where DHCP just refuses to work.   I've tried a lot of stuff, including reinstalling my driver.

If I connect to my home wifi with network-manager the status icon spins, then spins faster, then won't connect with DHCP.

If I try to connect to wifi with network-manager but when in and set things up manually, absolutely no problems.  It's what I'm typing on now.

It's getting really annoying since I use hotspots a lot!

I am not sure what information I can provide.  I'm NOT a newbie, but not an expert either.

Just to cover I've just done a fresh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

````
sudo dhclient -v
[sudo] password for jimmylaptop:
 
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5

Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.

All rights reserved.

For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/


Error getting interfaces; Permission denied
Can't get list of interfaces.

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
exiting.```
````

Comment: Have you ensured IPs are even being given out by the server?

Comment: Yes, my other computers work fine with this router, as do my phones.

Comment: ...or that the server has provisioned a large enough range of IPs to be handed out? have you looked in the logs during attempts, on the client and if any exist on the server?

Comment: Yeah it's just my simple home router.  It works on everything in my house.   Even on this laptop I have a dual install of windows/linux.  The DHCP works fine in windows.   So it's something going on weird in my system.

Comment: well i meant ensure you configured your router to give out enough.. ex) I only let my router give out 192.168.6.2---192.168.6.4. And sometimes i forget when I have added a device.... You need to try to obtain an address while looking at the logs... or go to the past logs and grep dhcp...  i believe you can run dhclient on the command line in debug mode too

Comment: it also may be helpful to watch the traffic on your interfaces to see what is coming and going while trying to obtain and address.. In a terminal `sudo tcpdump port bootpc and port bootps` ...you should see a conversation between your interface(s) and your router

Comment: Yes, low traffic.  It's an ongoing problem not only with my router, but every other router I try to get dhcp from.

Comment: ok... in a terminal do the command tcpdump command above.... let it sit... while that is running, open another terminal and do `tail -f /var/log/syslog` ... let that sit... then try to request an IP address on one of your interface by disabling it and enabling it again... then make note of what is taking place in the terminals

Comment: I'd suggest running `sudo dhclient -v` in a terminal and posting the output in your question. Perhaps your firewall is blocking the request?

Comment: okay steeldriver, it's posted above :)